# Multiple cross-references with cleveref with custom connecting word

Tags: cleveref

Suppose that I have two theorems in my text, Theorem 1 and Theorem 2, labeled `thm1` and `thm2`. Using the `cleveref` package and writing `\cref{thm1,thm2}` produces *Theorems 1 and 2*. Is there a way to change the connecting word "and", to, for instance, "or"? I am aware of the `crefmultiformat` command (§8.2.3 in the [manual](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf)), but that would change the behaviour of `cref` in the entire document, whereas there are some instances in which I would like the connecting word to be "and". Or should I just write `\cref{thm1} or \cref{thm2}`?

Comment: How about `\cref{thm1} or \ref{thm2}` to produce "theorem 1 or 2"? Note the singular form "theorem"; using the plural noun form -- as in "theorems 1 or 2" --  looks weird.

Comment: Yes, this could work – unless one changes the type of thm2 from a Theorem to, say, a Proposition, in which case the desired output would be "Theorem 1 or Proposition 2". The great advantage of cleveref is that it usually takes care of such changes.